# How to find the biggest VALUE (not a key) in a HashMap<Integer, Integer>?

Tags: java, hashmap, max, element

How to find the five?

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
hmap.put(98, 3);
hmap.put(-120, 2);
hmap.put(12, 5);
hmap.put(344, 1);
hmap.put(-220, 1);
```

I tried this but it doesn't like my hmap.

```
System.out.println(Collections.max(hmap));
```

Comment: Try a bit of googling, i will link you this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values--

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. My search engine very easily found this: [Finding the Highest Value in a Java Map](https://www.baeldung.com/java-find-map-max). [I downvoted because research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Comment: Stackoverflow is a great place to get your questions answered, but nothing can replace a good piece of research. There's a high probability that you'll come across a post which answers your exact question. Don't get nervous by the down-votes. Many people tend to use down-vote as a privilege.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the value of map using `hmap.values()` then use `Collections.max` to get max value

```
Collections.max(hmap.values());
```

Comment: If an answer resolves your issue, please try to mark it as accepted. This will help future visitors. You also have the option to up-vote.

Comment: You may wait a couple of days before deciding to accept an answer since more answers may be posted during that time. Accepting an answer eventually is good style (unless all answers are cr*p, of course, but this one is a good one, for example).

Comment: Agree with the concept of waiting time.It may help invite better/improved answers. As a side-note: accepted answers can also be unaccepted in favor of better answers.